# How to add custom shapes by finger touch as overlay on video in Flutter using ffmpeg?

Tags: flutter, android-ffmpeg

for a Flutter app that requires the user to select an image or a shape and add it by finger touch to a specific position in the video frame. I've found a way to add an overlay to a video using the ffmpeg package in Flutter, but I'm not sure how to implement the functionality in a way to be added by finger touch and then fix this edited frame for specified time then the video continues .
and I also want to ask if i can add this functionality to the Flutter video editor sdk

I have tried searching for examples and documentation on how to achieve this but couldn't find anything specific. I would appreciate any suggestions or guidance on how to proceed.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: How long have you been able to go for this approach? Show us some code and what is the error you're getting.

Comment: I am still searching to know if this is possible to be done with flutter or not . I haven't started yet